# Facebook Curl exception when publishing to album on facebook fan page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to publish a picture to an album on a facebook fan page. This works fine from my localhost. But when I try from my shared server, I get the error:

```
Error facebookserviceCurlException: 26: failed creating formpost data
```

I supply to the Facebook object the following parameters:

```
        $args = array(
                'message' => 'testing',
                'source' => "@".$params['source'],
                'aid' => $aid,
                'no_story' => 1,
                'access_token' => $fanpage_token
        );
```

And I set the facebook object to allow file uploads:

```
$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
```

On localhost, source is /var/www/publish_facebook/images/corn.jpg

On the server, I have tried 2 paths:

```
webspace/httpdocs/blog.webintelligence.ie/publish_facebook/images/corn.jpg
```

and

```
http://www.blog.webintelligence.ie/publish_facebook/images/corn.jpg
```

The second path, when viewed in a browser, displays the image. But I get the same error for both. Any ideas?

Comment: First path you tried doesn’t look like a complete absolute path – have you tried finding the actual path of your image file using `realpath`? Or you could also switch out the parameter `source` for one named `url` and give the HTTP URL to the image (without a leading `@`) – that way, Facebook will download the image from your server.

Comment: Thank you, using realpath worked